# Custom Type as Primary Key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance, code-first

I'm currently working with EF6 code-first on Visual Studio 2015.
I'm working on a database that I want to use user-defined types as primary keys.

This is a simple example of what I want:

```
public class ObjectIdType
{
    public string id { get; set; }
}
```

This will be the user-defined type.

```
public class ClasseProva
{

    [Key][DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public ObjectIdType Id { get; set; }

}
```

And this will be the entity where I want to use my custom type as PrimaryKey.

When I do this like the example an error occur when I try to create the controller, the error is: The property type is not a valid key type.

I found that you just can use scalar types as PK, but i'm wondering if I make my ObjectIdType inherit from String it will work? 
I tried to do it like this (obviously don't work):

```
public class ObjectIdType : String
{
    public string id { get; set; }
}
```

Is there any way to define my ObjectIdType as inheritance from String? Or there is any way to make a user-defined type a PK?

Comment: Can you give an example why exactly you would want to do this? Mostly when you want an object as primary key, you are building your database wrong.

Comment: Are you just trying to have a primary key that's composed of multiple columns?

Comment: @Jerodev My database is really huuuuge, and it is based on some big base classes that all the other entities inherit from them.The base entity uses ObjectIdType as his PK propertie type. What i want is to declare the ObjectIdType that would be a generic type for PKs and all the tables of my database will have their custom type of Id (CarIdType, HouseIdType) that will inherit from ObjectIdType. Did I explain it well?

Comment: @David No, what i'm trying is to define a custom type and then when I declare the PK on my entities I want them (the PKs) to be of my custom type. Did i explain it well?

Comment: @MarcPlanas: How do you expect that custom type to be represented in your relational database?  How will data integrity (such as uniqueness) be maintained with your custom type?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39663644/custom-string-as-primary-key-with-entity-framework?rq=1

Comment: I don't want to represent it as a table, I just want to make a Type.

Comment: `string` is already a (bad) "why don't you just dump anything you want in here" kind of "ID". If you want a human readable unique index field, then by all means use that for it. But the sole purpose of a primary key should be to uniquely *and very quickly* identify a row in a table. `string` comparison is slow(er). Why would you use anything other than `bigint` (`long`) or maybe even `int` or at most `uniqueidentifier` (`Guid`) as a primary key?

Comment: @MarcPlanas: If you don't want to use database tables then Entity Framework seems like the wrong choice of tools.  That's literally what that framework does, translate between code and relational databases.  A "primary key" doesn't mean anything to C#, only to SQL.

Comment: @David bro what i mean is that i don't want my custom type to be a table, but i want to use this custom type as the type of the PK from some tables, do u understand?

Comment: @MarcPlanas: Ok, then again... How do you want your custom type to be represented as the primary key in the table?  What do you want the resulting table structure to be?

Comment: Look at the question, the structure of ClasseProva is the table structure i want, using ObjectIdType as type of PK

Comment: @MarcPlanas - you might be able to teach the sql server of your choice your [custom data type](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/statements/create-type-transact-sql). But you won't be able to inherit from a [sealed](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/sealed) class (like: `string`)

Comment: @Corak its not possible to do it with EntityFramework?

Comment: @MarcPlanas: That's not a table structure, that's just a C# class.  You seem to be a bit confused about what Entity Framework actually does.  It basically translates your C# objects into SQL tables.  You're defining an object, but Entity Framework is telling you that it can't translate that object into a table structure.  So you need to change how you define your object.  What you need to keep in mind with your objects is *how they will be represented in SQL*.  Entity Framework (any ORM) is limited to the capabilities of the technologies it represents.

Comment: @MarcPlanas - It's not possible at all in C# (which EntityFramework is based on). Probably not even in anything .Net related. Or in any environment that has the explicit feature to make classes un-inheritable for that matter. (because why have it, if you can "easily" circumvent it?)

Comment: @David what i mean saying that it will be my table structure is that my table will got that columns of that types. I know what entity framework does...

Comment: @MarcPlanas: So your type has two values, a string and an int.  And you want your primary key to be composed of those two values, both the string and the int.  Remember earlier when you were asked if you wanted your primary key to be composed of multiple columns, and you said that's not what you want?  Now you're saying that is what you want.  I recommend you first define what it is you actually want to do and *then* try to implement it in code.

Comment: @David are u kidding? where do u see that i declared an attribute of type INT???

Comment: @MarcPlanas: Ah, that was my mistake.  So you have a string and a string.  (I admit to having assumed `int` likely because strings make *terrible* primary keys.)  The rest holds true.  Your custom type inherits `string` (well, tries to) and adds another `string` property to it.  Resulting in attempting to have two strings.  Two columns.  Composite key in SQL.  There are ways to have a composite key in EF, if that's your goal.  This isn't how you do that.  But if you can express that as what you *want* to do then we can help you do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any way to define my ObjectIdType as inheritance from String?

No. String is sealed.

> Or there is any way to make a user-defined type a PK?

Not 100% sure, but i think you can not do that.

Comment: what i want is ObjectIdType : String {.....}, is that what u mean that i can't do?

Comment: yes. that for sure you can not do it because String is a sealed class