# EF Core / DbContext > Map custom type as primary key

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

*Using the fluent api, how do I map a custom type as the primary key within my OnModelCreating method of the DbContext class?*

Using EF Core I'm trying to build a model for the follow entity.

```
public class Account
{
    public AccountId AccountId { get; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    private Account()
    {
    }

    public Account(AccountId accountId, string name)
    {
        AccountId = accountId;
        Name = name;            
    }
}
```

Where the primary key is the `AccountId`; the type is a simple value object like this.

```
public class AccountId
{
    public string Id { get; }

    public AccountId(string accountId)
    {
        Id = accountId;
    }
}
```

Within `OnModelCreating`, I found I can't map the `AccountId` without having a backing field. So I introduced the backing field `_accountId`. I don't want the AccountId to have a setter.

```
public class Account
{
    private string _accountId;
    public AccountId AccountId { get { return new AccountId(_accountId); } }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    private Account()
    {
    }

    public Account(AccountId accountId, string name)
    {
        _accountId = accountId.Id;
        Name = name;            
    }
}
```

But I still can't figure out how you specify a property with a backing field which is also the primary key.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    var account = modelBuilder.Entity<Account>();

    account.ToTable("Accounts");
    account.HasKey(x => x.AccountId);
    account.Property(x => x.AccountId).HasField("_accountId");
}
```

The OnModelCreating throws an exception on the property map line (`account.Property(x => x.AccountId).HasField("_accountId");`).
Stating that property and field have to be the same type.

Comment: Why do you need to introduce a new type and not just use string instead?

Comment: @MBakardzhiev I'm starting to question that - I wanted methods that accept the account id to be more explicit and less fragile to refactor changes. e.g. the constructor for Account takes accountid and name, if I swapped the args then I'll get compile time error but I wouldn't if they were both strings.

Comment: @MBakardzhiev I appreciate that I'm trying to cut corners and use the Account class as both my database dto and my domain object for business logic but I wanted to see if I *could* write it this way rather than question whether I *should*.

Comment: I found this one question similar to yours https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46098923/custom-type-as-primary-key, it is about EF standart, unfortunately it doesn't have an answer that may help you. I would not be surprised if such option is intentionally not included in EF.

Comment: Currently owned type is the closest, but it's tracked by reference like entity. Eventually the incoming EF Core 2.1 type conversions might help.

Comment: @MBakardzhiev A common reason is to use specific, but compatible, types as [Refinement Types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refinement_type) - as C# doesn't have native-support for refinement-types or dependent-types it's commonplace to use a custom type with implicit conversions as a substitute (usually a `struct`, but classes can work too - personally I'd have had `struct AccountId` to reduce heap allocations).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As pointed out, one can use a custom typed property as entity key by taking advantage of the **[Value Conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions)** feature in **EF Core 2.1**

So in your own example instead of mapping the property to a backing field, you can now define a custom conversion for it like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    ...
    account.HasKey(x => x.AccountId);
    account.Property(x => x.AccountId)
        .HasConversion(
            v => v.Id,
            v => new AccountId(v));
}
```

As described in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions), also a ValueConverter class can be implemented to make the conversion reusable and many custom converters are also provided out of the box.

Note: It's a good idea to implement `IComparable` and `IComparable<T>` for your custom `AccountId` class. Because EF Core seems to sort your changed entities based on their Keys internally for batch operations and you would receive an exception if your Key is not comparable!

Comment: This is a good idea, but doesn't work for multi-valued objects, as noted here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions#limitations

Comment: I am facing a problem when setting a converter for a `key`: if the type is a `class` when adding a new entity a `key` cannot be `null` and an exception is thrown; if the type is a struct (so it cannot be null) it works **but** the key cannot be set as `auto-increment` - well I cannot find a way to set it auto-increment.

Comment: Anyone get this to work when building relationships as a Single Navigation Property (aka the child does not have a property relating to the parent (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships))? When I use `Set<Account>().Include(a => a.Children)` the children collection is always emtpy. When i make the `Id` an integer instead of an `AccountId` then my `Include` works