# EF Core non-primitive type value object as primary key?

Tags: entity-framework-core, domain-driven-design

I've been trying to use a value object as a unique id in entity framework core.  I've gotten to the point where it is saving to the database correctly, but EF is not querying the database correctly to find my entity.  It looks like EF is loading the whole table, then doing the mapping in memory. When I look at the query it does not include a predicate for the id.

I'm dealing with an existing database that uses 10 character string ids with padded zeros so I'm seeing if working with them as value objects is going to work.  My next thing to try is just use a Guid and have the 'SalesOrderNumber' as a separate field.  That's just for this case though, what I'm really trying to figure out is if it is possible to use a value object as an primary key in entity framework.

Entity:

```
public class SalesOrder: Entity<SalesOrderNumber>
    {
        private SalesOrder() { }

        public SalesOrder(SalesOrderNumber id, DateTime dueDate)
        {
            Id = id;
            DueDate = dueDate;
            Open = true;
        }

        public override SalesOrderNumber Id { get; protected set; }
        public DateTime DueDate { get; private set; }
        public bool Open { get; private set; }
    }
```

Value Object:

```
  public class SalesOrderNumber: ValueObject
    {
        private readonly string _salesOrderNumber;

        public SalesOrderNumber(string salesOrderNumber)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(salesOrderNumber) || salesOrderNumber.Length > 10)
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"Sales Order Number  {salesOrderNumber} is invalid");

            _salesOrderNumber= salesOrderNumber;
        }

        protected override IEnumerable<object> GetAtomicValues()
        {
            yield return _salesOrderNumber;
        }

        public override string ToString() => _salesOrderNumber;
    }
```

DB Config:

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<SalesOrder> builder)
        {
            builder.HasKey(e => e.Id);
            builder.Property(e => e.Id).HasConversion(number => number.ToString(), s => new SalesOrderNumber(s));

        }
```

I've reviewed some other SO posts but none of them have addressed the query issue I've run into:
[EF Core / DbContext > Map custom type as primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49607375/ef-core-dbcontext-map-custom-type-as-primary-key)

Comment: WorkOrderNumber should be SalesOrderNumber, right? Same goes for "Work order number ...".

Comment: @Hermann.Gruber Yes! My mistake.  Was working with both, somehow mixed them up.  Fixed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The performance problem you laid out seems to be an open issue reported on github:
[EF Core non-primitive type value object as primary key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53328201/ef-core-non-primitive-type-value-object-as-primary-key)

Someone also reported a quick fix:
https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/13669#issuecomment-439589393
If I understood the quick fix right, adding implicit conversion operator from the value object to the backing primitive type, and an implicit conversion operator for the backward direction, may resolve your issue. Please leave a comment if this works for you.

Comment: Nice!  Awesome find!  I will be testing this out soon, thanks for pointing this out.  I'll have to spend some more time on the EF core github.

Comment: After finally getting around to trying this out, it was almost the solution, but does not work for Guid.  7 Days ago the EF Core team posted a bug fix that addresses the issue that is set to be released in 3.0

Comment: @ErpaDerp Fine! Would you mind posting a github link to the issue you mentioned?

Comment: Is it possible to convert non-primitive value object containing two fields? :
`public class MyId { public int CompanyId; public int UserId }`

Comment: @zolty13 Yes, it is possible. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions?tabs=data-annotations#the-valueconverter-class

Answer (score 0):

Even though an answer was provided id like to offer my findings on the subject.

#### Custom Object

The following wont work, it does compile but causes irregularity (in my case some of the properties didn't load at times)

```cs
public sealed class CustomValueObjectAsKey
{
    public CustomValueObjectAsKey(string value)
    {
        //Validation
        Value = value;
    }

    //For deserializing
    private CustomValueObjectAsKey()
    {

    }

    public string Value { get; private set; }
}
```

#### Record

Writing the key as record was working as intended.

```cs
public sealed record CustomValueObjectAsKeyRecord(string C);
```

#### Equals and GetHashCode

After understanding what makes the record work I found out that your valueobject must be identifiable and equitable (duh!)

```cs
 public sealed class CustomValueObjectAsKeyImitateRecord : IEquatable<CustomValueObjectAsKeyImitateRecord >
 {
     public CustomValueObjectAsKeyImitateRecord(string c) : base()
     {
         C = c;
     }

     private Type EqualityContract => typeof(CustomValueObjectAsKeyImitateRecord);

     public string C { get; set; }

     public override int GetHashCode()
     {
         return EqualityComparer<Type>.Default.GetHashCode(EqualityContract) * -1521134295 + EqualityComparer<string>.Default.GetHashCode(C);

         //This also works : return HashCode.Combine(C);
     }

     public override bool Equals(object obj)
     {
         return Equals(obj as CustomValueObjectAsKeyImitateRecord);
     }

     public bool Equals(CustomValueObjectAsKeyImitateRecord other)
     {
         return (object)this == other || ((object)other != null && EqualityContract == other.EqualityContract && EqualityComparer<string>.Default.Equals(C, other.C));
     }
 }
```

Tested on .NET 6 and 7
And on EF core 6.0.22 and 7.0.11

Dont forget the convetion :

```cs
var converter = new ValueConverter<CustomValueObjectAsKeyImitateRecord, string>(
    v => v.ToString(),
    v => new CustomValueObjectAsKeyImitateRecord(v));

 builder.Entity<Yeet1>().HasKey(p => p.Id);
 builder.Entity<Yeet1>()
     .Property(p => p.Id)
     .HasConversion(converter);
```

Hope that saves hours of debugging and existence questioning for the future.